How to remove getpagespeed yum repo from RHEL?
My company used to subscribe to the getpagespeed repo, but now we have decided to use the nginx.org repo with the possibility of switching to nginx plus in the future. Since we don't need the getpagespeed repo anymore, how can I cleanly remove it from our RHEL system?
I've renamed the /etc/yum.repos.d/getpagespeed-extras.conf file to /etc/yum.repos.d/getpagespeed-extras.conf.disabled, but the yum search nginx command still lists getpagespeed packages.

just add/change a line in the conf/repo file
enabled=0
it should do its job

Where is it located?

Selamat malam,
The command to remove the repository is:
yum remove getpagespeed-extras-release

You will have also to delete the manually renamed file, e.g.:
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/getpagespeed-extras.conf.disabled

